# IntelliJ wrongly suggests to make method static in Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I am having a simple register component that does nothing more than submitting a form into nirvana. However, IntelliJ suggests that `onSubmit` could be `static`. If I change the signature to `static` I cannot call that method - at least as far as I can tell - all answers suggest that one cannot call a static component method from within the template.

Apparently IntelliJ does not realize, that I am actually calling this method in the template and thus wrongly suggests to make the method `static`.

Is there a workaround or will I just have to live with that warning?

Here is an example:

Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  constructor() {
    this.data = {
      username: ''
    };
  }

  // WARNING: Method can be static
  onSubmit(event) {
    alert('Submitting ..');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Template:

```xml
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">    
  <mat-grid-list cols=1>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="data.username" name="uname">
    </mat-form-field>    
    <mat-grid-list cols=2>
      <button mat-button type="submit">Ok</button>
      <button mat-button>Cancel</button>
    </mat-grid-list>

  </mat-grid-list>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellij suggests making this kind of methods static because they don't touch any of the state of an instance.

You can make the onSubmit method static:

```
static onSubmit(event) {
    alert('Submitting ..');
}
```

and then intellij is going to warn you to place this method before the non static methods of your class.

Then, you need to provide a getter in the component to call static members from the template as you do.

```
onSubmit = RegisterComponent.onSubmit;
```

So, your code should be:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  onSubmit = RegisterComponent.onSubmit;

  static onSubmit(event) {
    alert('Submitting ..');
  }

  constructor() {
    this.data = {
      username: ''
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This will work and you'll have no warnings.

Comment: "because they don't touch any of the state of an instance". I think this is the exact reason, and it's well-explained.

Comment: This seems a bit ridiculous though - you're basically just adding extra code to keep the IDE happy (because it's trying to do the right thing, but doesn't properly understand the Angular framework). Why not just suppress the inspection on that line? Or even disable it altogether, as for an Angular project it's probably going to cause more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: Or! Just disable the inspection. For angular projects it's in my opinion silly to make component methods static.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to suppress this warning is to use the alt-enter shortcut on the warning - or click on the light bulb when the cursor is in the code causing the warning - and then use the right arrow key to trigger the related dropdown which has options to suppress the warning.